# Does calling a function multiple times decrease the programm speed?

Tags: c++, function

I just have a quick question.

1.

```
sf::Vector2f position = player.getPosition();
std::cout << position.x << " " << position.y << '\n';
```

2.

```
std::cout << player.getPosition().x << " " << player.getPosition().y << '\n';
```

Is the first way theoretically faster than the second way?  Because the second way calls the same function 2 times.

Comment: Depends on a lot of factors (such as how good the compiler is at optimizing, what the function returns, etc.), so you'll have to measure it yourself.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic as this is entirely implementation specific. All depends on what the `getPosition()` call actually does. It it doing calculations point-in-time? Or is it simply returning a cached-object?

Comment: You could dissassemble the code and see what it compiles down to, though it's usually best not to rely on your compiler being smart for any cross platform project(especially when considering game platforms). Also, if `getPosition` returns a `const` reference, then you've no need to copy its return value.

Comment: `getPosition()` *does*  return a const reference to a member object and is 1 line of code. The `<<` operator is taking several orders of magnitude longer than the function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Usually* calling a function multiple times **does** make the program go slower.

For each function call, the context needs to be saved (program counter, local variables, etc) and a new stack frame needs to be created, where local variables created inside that function are saved.

So, each time you call a function, all of that happens. And that is without taking into account how much time the function needs to process whatever it has to process.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe. It depends.

Calling a function multiple times can be slower than calling the function once.

However, if an optimizer can prove that the function has no side-effects, then it will be able to reduce the multiple function calls to one. If the optimizer generates identical output for both alternatives, then there will not be any decrease in program speed.